# git revert a merge: determine which parent is which (-m 1 vs -m 2)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log, git-revert

I am trying to revert a merge, but I don't know whether to use `git revert -m 1 <merge commit's sha>` or `git revert -m 2 <merge commit's sha>`. How do I find out which parent is `-m 1` and which parent is `-m 2`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, the super-short answer is that it's always `-m 1`. :-) But this deserves some explanation:

- The parents are ordered, and commands like `git log` and `git show` show the order:

  > ```
  > commit c13c783c9d3d7d3eff937b7bf3642d2a7fe32644
  > Merge: 3f7ebc6ec 39ee4c6c2
  > ```

  so here `3f7ebc6ec` is parent #1 and `39ee4c6c2` is parent #2.
- The suffix `^` operation takes these same values:

  > ```
  > $ git rev-parse c13c783c9d3d7d3eff937b7bf3642d2a7fe32644^1
  > 3f7ebc6ece46f1c23480d094688b8b5f24eb345c
  > ```

  (and of course `...^2` would be the other one).
- Programs that draw the graph, including `git log --graph`, will show you how these connect.
- But most importantly, **the *first* parent of any merge is the commit that was current when you made the merge.**

In particular, this means that if you are on branch `main` and run `git merge sidebranch`, the commit you make now (if all goes well) or eventually (if you must resolve the merge by hand) has, as its *first* parent, the previous tip of the `main` branch.  Its second parent is therefore the tip of `sidebranch`.

Suppose, then, that we have this to start with:

```
...--o--*--A--B------C   <-- main
         \
          D--E--F--G--H   <-- sidebranch
```

when we run `git merge`.  The common base commit is `*`, and Git makes a new merge commit M by doing, in essence:

1. `git diff * C` (what did we change?)
2. `git diff * H` (what did they change?)

and then combining these two sets of changes and applying those to `*`, giving us this final result:

```
...--o--*--A--B------C--M   <-- main
         \             /
          D--E--F--G--H   <-- sidebranch
```

Now, if everything changed in `A-B-C` is completely independent of everything in changed in `D-E-F-G-H`, it would not matter too much precisely *how* Git did the revert, as long as it kept the `A-B-C` changes while ditching the `D-E-F-G-H` changes.

But what if `B` is mostly the same as `F`, i.e., both `B` and `F` fix a bug?  In that case, we *don't* want to undo the shared changes from `B` and `F`, that Git took one copy of.  **This is where the `-m 1` part comes in.**

When `git revert` goes to undo some changes, it run its own `git diff`.  The `git diff` it runs compares the commit you want to revert, to its parent.  For any ordinary non-merge commit, this is easy: compare `B` vs `A`, or `E` vs `D`, or whatever, to see what happened, and back it out.  With a merge commit, though, it's not obvious which parent to compare to (except that it kind of is :-) ).  The *first* parent here is `C`, so let's see what we get if we run:

```
git diff C M
```

The changes between `C` and `M` are those we picked up by *adding* the changes from `D-E-F-G-H` to the changes we *already had* in `A-B-C`, if we compare `M` vs `*`.  In other words:

- If `B` and `F` overlap 100%, the changes in `C`-vs-`M` are `D-E-G-H`: everything *except* the overlap.  So we wind up reverting just those.
- If `F` has *more* changes in it than `B`, the changes in `C`-vs-`M` are `D-E-(some-of-F)-G-H`:  We wind up reverting those changes, but not the ones in `B`.
- If `F` has *fewer* changes in it than `B`, the changes in `C`-vs-`M` are just `D-E-G-H` again, and we wind up reverting just those.

Since the first parent is `C`, and we want to back out the `D-E-F-G-H` changes (excluding any we already had via `A-B-C`), we want `-m 1` in this revert.

Comment: This is a very well thought out answer. Thank you!

Comment: beautiful answer! how could conflicts arise when reverting, in your examples?